# Hive2 JDBC exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, beeline

I'm running hive 2.1.1, hadoop 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

It is totally fine to do HQL in the hive terminal.

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
Time taken: 0.799 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> show tables;
OK
Time taken: 0.027 seconds
hive> create table test1(id int, name string);
OK
Time taken: 0.928 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
test1
Time taken: 0.021 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

This is the error I get from JDBC in beeline and Java:

> Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error,
>   return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   MetaException(message:Got exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied:
>   user=hive2, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user/hive/warehouse/test2":server:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x

I get the same error when I try insert query in both beeline and Java. **It seems I can only read but not write through JDBC.**

Here's how I log in in beeline:

```
Beeline version 2.1.1 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: hive2
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: ********
```

Here's piece of my Java code:

```
try(
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hive2", "password");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {
        ...
    }
```

I tried to set up the hive.exec.stagingdir property in hive-site.xml:

```
 <property>
     <name>hive.exec.stagingdir</name>
     <value>/tmp/hive-staging</value>
 </property>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.

Another solution I found is to log-in as a root user. But how could I log-in as a **root user** instead of user [**hive2**]?

How could I execute the write query (create, insert) through JDBC without getting the Permission denied error?

Thank you!

Comment: What about adding user `hive2` to group `supergroup`? Because the error message states clearly that your Hive Warehouse dir belongs to user `server` *(could be a dummy label, actually, HDFS does not check user & group names against Linux lists)* and group  `supergroup` with privileges `o=rwx,g=rwx,o=r-x`

Comment: Of course, since it's an HDFS privilege issue, you will have to run the `usermod -G` command on *all* cluster nodes -- not only the one running HiveServer2, but also NameNodes and DataNodes...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for point that out! I try to log in as 'server' and it works! I'm now running all the nodes on a single instance. I will remember your suggestion when I deploy hadoop to a cluster.